# querysyntaxexception in Hibernate even if i give class and entity name in HQL with proper mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a hibernate. I am getting below Exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: DBCDataSource is not mapped [from DBCDataSource where upper(datasourceType) = upper('BAC_MANAGEMENT')]
```

I searched in net and got answer as in HQL we need to use class names and property names instead of table and column names. The query was using column name so i have changed it ti use property name after that also exception dint went. I have checked in HIbernate.cfg.xml the for any missing mapping but i found mapping s correct. Find ma code below.

```
previous query-->list =  session.createQuery("from DBCDataSource where upper(DATASOURCE_TYPE) = upper('" + type +"')").list();
DATASOURCE_TYPE is a column name

Modified to-->list =  session.createQuery("from DBCDataSource where upper(datasourceType) = upper('" + type +"')").list();
datasourceType is a propery name mapped to tat column.
```

### Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dict_db_ds")
public class DBCDataSource implements Serializable{
.
.
.

@Column(name = "DATASOURCE_TYPE")
    private String datasourceType;

}
```

### Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
..
..
 <mapping class="com.hp.bto.bsmr.collection.dao.omi.DBCDataSource" /> 
..
..
```

am i missing further??

Kindly advice..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 list =  session.createQuery("from DBCDataSource where "
              +"upper(datasourceType) =:type")
             .setParameter("type", type)
             .list();
```

Comment: I have tried this but exception still persists.. so i tries with another method which is createSqlQuery() method by replacing all class nd property names with table nd column names.. i am getting the output.. but its affecting other parts while iterating and most of the places.. so needed som way to sort it out through createQuery or HQL only..

Comment: Are you getting same exception??

Comment: Ya after modifying according your suggestion i am getting same exception..but after using createSqlQuery instead of createQuery that exception s not coming but its affecting other parts of the program. So trying to figure out some way to resolve using createQuery or HQL. Any other suggestions can you give??